# How to get label value from Picturebox on Picturebox click event

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, flowlayoutpanel

I have tried many ways to read label value from PictureBox when a user clicks PictureBox which is inside of flowLayoutPanel1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq5vP.jpg)
Anyone help me on this.

From the attached image, I want to read price value when the user clicks on the "PictureBox Click Event".

```
pic.Click += new EventHandler(picture_click);
void picture_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (pic != null) {
        pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        pic = (PictureBox)sender;
        pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code?  What language?  I'm assuming some dot net one

Comment: I don't have proper code, I used like pic.Click += new EventHandler(picture_click);

void picture_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pic != null)
            {
                pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                pic = (PictureBox)sender;
                pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;  
            } 
        }

Comment: Its C# for Winform

Comment: See the attached Picture and you will have some idea what is my actual requirement.

Comment: Is the text part of the picture box or a separate label?

Comment: If the text is part of the image you will need ocr. If there are actual Label controls, we need to see the code that creates them.

Comment: Its separate lable box which i have added in flowLayoutPanel.

//Price add
                Price = new Label();
                Price.Text = "Rs." + Myadp["Menu_Price"].ToString() + "/-";
                Price.Width = 65;
                Price.Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                Price.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 121, 121);
                Price.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

When user click the respective menu It will add into the Datagridview, for that i need to get label value from PictureBox while Click event

Comment: Since the labels and picture boxes are separate, you need to map them to each other, i.e. picture1 -> label1, picture2 -> label2, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control c in pic.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType().Name == "Label")
                {
                    if(pic.Controls.IndexOf(c).ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        _Prc = c.Text.Replace("Rs.", "");
                        _Prc = _Prc.Replace("/-", "");
                    }
                    else if (pic.Controls.IndexOf(c).ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        _Menu = c.Text;
                    } 
                }
            }
```